# Converting label expression from VBScript to Python in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.4, python-parser, vbscript

I have a feature class with label expression in VB script. I do not have the skill to convert a VB script to a python script.

Here is the VBScript:-

```vb
Function FindLabel ( [DESCRIPTION]  )
  if (left( [name] ,4) = "ABCD") then
   FindLabel =PCase( MID( [DESCRIPTION] , 19, 100))
  else
   FindLabel = PCase( [DESCRIPTION] )
  end if
End Function

Function PCase(strInput)
 Dim iPosition
 Dim iSpace
 Dim strOutput
 iPosition = 1
 Do While InStr(iPosition, strInput, " ", 1) <> 0
 iSpace = InStr(iPosition, strInput, " ", 1)
 strOutput = strOutput & UCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition, 1))
 strOutput = strOutput & LCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition + 1, iSpace - iPosition))
 iPosition = iSpace + 1
 Loop
 strOutput = strOutput & UCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition, 1))
 strOutput = strOutput & LCase(Mid(strInput, iPosition + 1))
 PCase = strOutput
 End Function
```

I came up with following python code. But it did not work:-

```py
def FindLabel([DESCRIPTION]):
    if [name][:4]=='ABCD':
        FindLabel = PCase( [DESCRIPTION][19:100] )
    else:
        FindLabel = PCase( [DESCRIPTION] )

def PCase(strInput):
    iSpace=strInput.find(" ", beg=0, end=len(strInput))
    iPosition=1
    while iSpace!=0:
        iSpace=strInput.find(" ", beg=0, end=len(strInput))
        strOutput=strOutput+strInput[0:1].upper()
        strOutput=strOutput+strInput[iPosition+1:iSpace-iPosition].lower()
        iPosition=iSpace+1
    strOutput=strOutput+strInput[iPosition:1].upper()
    strOutput=strOutput+strInput[iPosition+1:].lower()
    return strOutput
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert it?

Comment: My ArcGIS for Server is installed in Linux. That's why.

Comment: Could you tell us what the script is trying to do and what errors you have seen? It looks like you're trying to convert the string to title case, so [DESCRIPTION][19:100].title() would do that. No need for PCase function.

Comment: @SnehilKandpal Please **[edit]** your question to detail what your current VBS label code does, and what happens when you try to convert it to python.

Comment: There are many many issues with your code.  The logic in VBScript does not translate directly into Python

Answer (score 3):

You will get the result that I think you're after by using the code below.

This looks at the value of field `name`, and if it starts with `ABCD` it will return a label for field `Description` starting at the 19th character, and if the `name` field doesn't begin with `ABCD` it will return the entire `Description` value.

The label will capitalise the first letter of every word.

```py
def FindLabel([Description], [name]):
    if [name][:4]=='ABCD':
        return [Description][19:100].title()
    else:
        return [Description].title()
```

The assumption is that records that have a `name` that starts with `ABCD` have a 19 digit code at the start of the `Description` that you want to strip off when labelling.

Note that `[Description][19:100]` will stop the label at the 100th character too.  If you wish to include longer values you can use just `[Description][19:]]` which won't strip any text from the end of the label.

---

The code below is a rewrite of the code in the question, and will cope with punctuation in the `Description` string which `str.title()` may not allow for.

```py
def FindLabel([Description], [name]):
    if [name][:4]=='ABCD':
        return PCase( [Description][19:100] )
    else:
        return PCase( [Description])

def PCase(strInput):
    strOutput = ""
    spc = strInput.find(" ", 0, len(strInput))
    while spc != -1:
        strOutput += strInput[:1].upper() + strInput[1:spc+1]
        strInput = strInput[spc+1:]
        spc = strInput.find(" ", 0, len(strInput))

    strOutput += strInput[:1].upper() + strInput[1:]

    return "'{}'".format(strOutput.strip())
```